# Should I report any odd voting behavior?

Tags: support, voting

I'm flattered that someone was willing to do this:

[image: History]

but it seems odd to me... it's in my favor but I'd like to be honest about it. Should I report such behavior (in the future) or just leave it alone?

Comment: I've downvoted those five questions.  You should be all set now.

Comment: do you know what's weird? Only questions are upvoted.

Comment: I've had this happen a few times, and it was always question upvotes as well - it is a bit "weird".

Comment: @Nick: That's not so strange in my case -- I've asked a *lot* of questions. (More than pretty much any other 20k+ user I think)

Comment: @Billy: I find it strange because, like what @Wesley mentioned, I had some of [my questions been upvoted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/49641/) in a similar pattern :)

Comment: I've seen this odd all-questions voting pattern recently, too.  Could it be from people that are angling for the Electorate badge?

Answer (score 9):

**Leave it alone.**  There is a *background process* that runs every so often (around every 24 hours) that *checks for fraudulent votes and removes them.*

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes I find a question strikingly provocative or an answer strikingly brilliant. When this happens, I usually check out the profile of the user, and browse some of his or her other questions or answers to find more pearls of wisdom. I upvote the ones I like. This isn't vote fraud, just flattery.

Comment: But when you do that, you do have to take some time to read the various things as you're making your decisions. All these happened at the exact same time (or within 3 minutes of each other)

Comment: @Billy: Well, I usually open lots of tabs to read them. It can happen all within an hour, I suppose. Depends on what I'm procrastinating from, really.

Comment: ROFL -- like I'm doing right now you mean? :P

Comment: Be careful how many you upvote though -- I don't know how the magic recalc works -- but it does detect this sort of behavior and throw it all away.

Comment: Only if his voting graph is highly skewed. A few upvotes to one person alongside 20+ upvotes to other people isn't really vote fraud.